# Clearing reserved space in a luks encrypted volume

Tags: partition, ext4, luks

I was just checking my LUKS encrypted volume which is mounted the following way.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdd1 z1vol
sudo mount /dev/mapper/z1vol /mnt/hdz1/
```

I discovered that I had a reserved block count of 48837683 using

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/z1vol
```

I would like to set the reserve space to zero and expand the area occupied by the LUKS encrypted volume. How would I do that? Is the following going to work (I am hesitant to try it without confirmation)?

```
sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/mapper/z1vol
```

If the LUKS volume is like a truecrypt partition, simply expanding the underlying partition will not increase the encrypted partition.

Comment: _Never_ reduce the reserved space to zero. Filesystems behave badly when absolutely all space is exhausted. Leave 1-2% reserved space.

Comment: It's just for storage of backups.

Comment: I've done this with a general data storage SSD, also encrypted, but set it to just over 1GB of reserved space just in case. To set the reserved space to `0.3%` you can use `-m 0.3`.

Comment: So sudo tune2fs -m 0.3 /dev/mapper/z1vol actually does expand the LUKS volume?