# How important is LUKS reserved block count for external drive?

Tags: hard-disk, luks, data

I have LUKS FDE on my external data HDD but recently almost filled it up. When cleaning it up I noticed that the available and free counters don't match.

Read that LUKS reserves 5% of total capacity for "root user and system processes" and that reducing it could lead to loss of data. In my case that takes up 250GB of space on a 5TB HDD.

What I want to know is what and how important of a role this plays and what is the minimum reserved space that is needed in case of external HDDs (that doesn't have bootable partitions).

Does reducing the reserved blocks significantly increase the risk of data loss or make it non-mountable? I want to find a good balance between data safety and disk usage.

Edit: Found this answer : [Clearing reserved space in a luks encrypted volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334526/clearing-reserved-space-in-a-luks-encrypted-volume) which speak of reducing to 1GB (0.3% of capacity) for a backup drive. Is that safe or does that pose any significant risk of data loss ? I was planning to let 0.5-1 % if that is acceptable.

Comment: *Read that LUKS reserves 5% of total capacity for "root user and system processes"* that sounds totally wrong. LUKS is not a file system – it has no notion of "users". It's also not a process scheduler – it has no notion of "processes". So, something is wrong in how you understand your problem!

Comment: integrity and other special features aside, LUKS uses a fixed size for the LUKS header and that's it. by default this would be 16M for a LUKS2 header. everything else is the responsibility of the filesystem. If you are referring to the ext4 root reserve you can adjust it or disable entirely with tune2fs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller @frostschutz You are right, I misunderstood that statement. Ran `tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/luks-..` and got the reserved block size and mistakenly associated the reservation being done by LUKS.  If this is by ext4 is it safe to reduce this to 0.5-1 % range safely ?

Comment: We can't tell you that. It depends on what you're using that disk for. Generally, that amount of reserved space is such that if the file system is used as a system disk, at least the log files of programs that fail due to running out of disk space can be written, and such that filesystem tools have some free space when resizing the image. If you don't do either, you don't need that reserved space.

Comment: Mine is a external HDD where I backup images and videos man ually. Sometimes I download files directly into the HDD or move them between HDDs so there is a small risk I might near the limits occasionally. There is no OS installed nor is it used for application data.

Comment: Then you can safely reduce the reserved block count all the way to zero. For an external HDD for image/video backup purposes, that is only used by you personally, there is no reason to keep any disk space reserved for root.

Comment: You can also specify the absolute reserved block count / size, rather than a percentage. You can set it to 0. None of it matters, as long as you don't actually run out of space. If you do run out of space, you might hit some bad performance + fragmentation issues, as the filesystem scrambles to collect leftover tiniest free space segments.

Comment: @frostschutz I have set to 0.5% of capacity for now. I can live with fragmentation as I tend to target 90% filled by deleting or eventually adding storage. My primary concern was loosing all data or make it inaccessible ( unable to mount or decrypt LUKS ) if I accidentally filled it upto 100% and there were no reserved space. I can live with 0.5% for data safety.